# How to resolve clashing npm packages on Mac OSX?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I'm trying to work through a tutorial by Mike Bostock on Medium - https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-1-897aa8f8ca2c#.7r3ujdpq5 - which involves installing a package, thus:

```
npm install -g shapefile
```

However, when I try to run the next step:

```
shp2json cb_2014_06_tract_500k.shp -o ca.json
```

I receive the following error message:

```
error: First argument to DataView constructor must be an ArrayBuffer
```

Given the warning by Mike about an unrelated package, I'm guessing the following package has been installed - https://github.com/patosai/shp2json-js

How do I check, and more importantly, how do I resolve the issue so I can continue with the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Base on the error message, I believe that you installed the correct package. However since you install it globally (-g flag), sudo permission must be provided in order to make change to system files.
I suggest reinstall it using:

`sudo npm remove -g shapefile
sudo npm install -g shapefile`

Comment: If `sudo` was required, the initial installation would have failed, and the question doesn't in any way hint to that happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem-

I solved it, but I cannot pinpoint the exact problem for you- I'm guessing you're missing a dependency somewhere in you computer.

For me,
It seems I had node / NPM installed, but did not install it with homebrew.

I had to update homebrew to work with OSX Sierra- and then installed node with homebrew.

updating homebrew required a command that I found here-
https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/476

Hope this helps!